# Hiking near Barcelona - or alternative hiking cities close-by?

Tags: budget, nature-and-wildlife, hiking, barcelona

I am going to Barcelona in the start of July together with a friend. We have 3 to 4 days (in Barcelona) and we want to see some beautiful nature and the possibility to hike, and we also want to spend as little money as possible. The budget is quite tight.

If there is nothing in Barcelona, we are open to other destinations, as long as it's relatively cheap getting there (train/plane).

Unfortunately one of us will have a 20 kg suitcase, so it would be great if we could have a hotel and then make daily trips.

Comment: There are a lot of small towns in the hills north of Barcelona. I had a very nice trip to Banyoles a few years ago, for rowing rather than hiking, but it was cheap + friendly + apparently lots of walking about. Also fairly easy to get to from Barcelona on the bus. I'd suggest you look for places similar to that!

Comment: Mount tibidabo is definitely hikeable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nearest one from Barcelona is [Sant Llorenç del Munt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sant_Lloren%C3%A7_del_Munt) (30 minutes by car). There is a monastery on the top of the mountain.

[image]

Alternatively you can go to [Parc Natural del Montseny.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montseny_Massif) (1 hour by car).
[image]

Answer (score 6):

If your budget is tight and you are going to spend only a few days in Barcelona - so schedule is tight, too - I would suggest [Collserola](https://www.parcnaturalcollserola.cat/en/).

It is a natural park close to the city - close enough to get there by underground - so it's possible to go there for the price of a metro ticket, hike for a day or half a day and return to the city.

I must admit that the options on the other answer (Montseny or Sant Llorenç de Munt) and the even better [Montserrat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montserrat_(mountain)) are larger, more natural and probably more beautiful, and there are even some places in the Pyrenees that are close enough for a one day hiking trip from Barcelona, but they are hard - and more expensive - to reach by public transport.

Furthermore, in Collserola you can find some beautiful natural places and some impressive views over Barcelona and neighbouring cities.

Comment: I know that the question is several years old and that the answer is not likely going to be useful to the original poster, but I answered the question for the potential benefit of future readers.

Comment: Note that reacing Montserrat is just 5€ or so (the price of the FGC ticket), then you can hike from Aeri de Montserrat or Monistrol.